# Gcloud pushes image to wrong/old project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

In Google cloud, I had an old project ( myproj-test-302801 ), I blew it away and started a new one ( myproj-307522 ). But now every time I try and push my image I get...

```
$ gcloud.cmd compute instances update-container myproj-test --container-image=gcr.io/myproj-307522/myproj:0.8
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.update-container) NOT_FOUND: The resource 'projects/myproj-test-302801' was not found
```

In other words, its like its finding my old project (myproj-test-302801) from who-knows where, and insisting on using it.

I have the project config set ok...

```
gcloud projects list
PROJECT_ID                NAME              PROJECT_NUMBER
myproj-307522             myproj            996908104657
```

I've tried setting it again..

```
gcloud config set project myproj-307522
```

If I push with the --project flag it works...

```
$ gcloud.cmd compute instances update-container myproj-test --container-image=gcr.io/myproj-307522/myproj:0.8 --project=myproj-307522
```

or the environment variable also works..

```
$ CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=holder-307522 gcloud.cmd compute instances update-container myproj-test --container-image=gcr.io/myproj-307522/myproj:0.8
```

I've looked through every config file I can find, I've done

```
gcloud config list
```

I've looked in /c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/properties and /c/Users/chris/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default, I've tried starting again with

```
gcloud init
```

and I can see no references anywhere to my old project name myproj-test-302801. I've checked that my images exist and are being uploaded to the new project's container registry. In short, the old project has gone, but gcloud still insists on using it unless I'm explicit with the --project flag.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to restart your computer?

Comment: rebooting doesn't help.

Comment: What are your environment variables? Are you sure that you haven't a bad one already set?

Comment: Are you using `gcloud.cmd` rather than `gcloud` for the `computer instances` commands (and only those, elsewhere you use `gcloud`)? I assume Windows but I'm less familiar with Windows. Is there a reason for using `gcloud.cmd` and only for those commands? It would appear that `gcloud.cmd` perhaps overrides `gcloud`'s environment on your machine.

Comment: I have no environment variables related to Google cloud. So for example, I don't have CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT set.

Comment: I'm using gcloud.cmd because this is windows, and even though I'm using cygwin, when I use gradle, it doesn't know about cygwin, so its easier to use gcloud.cmd in gradle... however... I just noticed that gcloud works, presumably running as a cygwin shell command. So this is odd. I just tried some things,

Comment: I turned echo on, in gcloud.cmd and I turned PYTHONVERBOSE=2 (gcloud uses python), and despite trawling through all the debug, there is no mention of myproj-test-302801, right up to the point where the error pops out. I also did an exhaustive search through ~/.docker, ~/.config, windows regedit for 302801, but came up with nothing. So it's a bit of a mystery, but must be somehow specific to gcloud.cmd, but how that could be, I can't imagine.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling entire [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#windows) ?

Comment: I'm at a loss. Presumably, if you use any other environment, this issue is not present? Perhaps using Cloud Shell (or `gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh` if that's supported on Windows?). If you have a support contract with Google, perhaps raise a ticket. Best to know the reason so the issue doesn't return.